# File handling in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, file-io

I am reusing some android code into my blackberry application. There is one line of code like this

```
File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
```

where cacheDir is a File & filename is a string.
But when implementing this same line in blackberry i get error

> "The constructor File(File, String) is
>   undefined".

Can anyone help me out.

**UPDATE**

Another error which i am facing is for this line

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

where `f` is the instance of FileConenction stream. The error says

> "The constructor
>   FileOutputStream(FileConnection) is
>   undefined"

can anyone help?

Comment: Hi! You can always edit you question to add new info so it will be easer to reuse your questions in future.

Answer (score 2):

Usual `File` Java API does not work on BB.

See BB API documentation for `javax.microedition.io.Connector` and `javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection`.

You will need to do something like:

```
FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///CFCard/newfile.txt");

// If no exception is thrown, then the URI is valid, but the file may or may not exist.
if (!fconn.exists()) fconn.create(); // create the file if it doesn't exist

OutputStream os = fconn.openOutputStream();

...

fconn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```java
Connector.open("file://" + dirName);
```

More info available [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-access-local-file-systems-from-j2me-devices-using-fileconnectio-2.html)

You can try this:

```java
OutputConnection connection = (OutputConnection)                     
    Connector.open("file://c:/myfile.txt;append=true", Connector.WRITE );
OutputStream out = connection.openOutputStream();
PrintStream output = new PrintStream( out );

output.println( "This is a test." );

out.close();
connection.close();
```

Taken from [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-write-to-a-file.html)

Comment: OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);where f is the instanace os FileConenction stream.The error says "The constructor FileOutputStream(FileConnection) is undefined"

Comment: I have modified my answer to respond your query.